# How to add the aggregated numbers in a file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, perl

I need to write a script which will add the values for the same string in different lines.

For example when a file contains the following:

```
abc,10
xyz,20,
abc,30,
ghd,40
xyz,10
```

script should check the matching string `abc`, `xyz` etc. in a file and add the values of it and redirect the output to new file.

The output should be:

```
abc,40,
xyz,30,
ghd,40
```

Can we write a script for this? Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: any reason for the trailing commas?

Answer (score 1):

Easy in Perl: use a hash to store the running sums.

```
perl -laF/,/ -ne '
    $h{ $F[0] } += $F[1];
    }{
    print "$_,$h{$_}" for keys %h;
' input-file > output-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` adds newlines to `print`
- `-a` splits each input line into the @F array
- `-F/,/` tells `-a` to split on commas
- `}{` is the "Eskimo greeting" operator, it separates the `-n` loop from the code that will run at the end of the input.

Comment: The simpler `-F,` also works

Comment: @glennjackman: Depends on the Perl version: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/pod/perldelta.pod#-F_now_implies_-a_and_-a_implies_-n but `-aF,` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about `bash`:

```
for i in $(cut -d ',' -f1 FILE  | sort | uniq)
do
    echo -n "$i", &&
    echo -n $(grep "^$i," FILE | cut -d',' -f2 | paste -sd+ - | bc)
    echo $(echo "$i" | grep -E -o ",$") || echo
done
```

Or if you're going to miss `,`:

```
for i in $(cut -d ',' -f1 FILE  | sort | uniq)
do
    echo -n "$i", &&
    echo -n $(grep "^$i," FILE | cut -d',' -f2 | paste -sd+ - | bc) &&
    grep -E -o "$i,[0-9]+,$" FILE >/dev/null && echo ',' || echo
done
```

Or if you want to save order of tokens:

```
for i in $(cut -d ',' -f1 FILE  | awk '!seen[$0]++')
do
    echo -n "$i", &&
    echo -n $(grep "^$i," FILE | cut -d',' -f2 | paste -sd+ - | bc) &&
    grep -E -o "$i,[0-9]+,$" FILE >/dev/null && echo ',' || echo
done
```

Replace `FILE` with an actual filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
          str[$1]+=$2;
          next
     }

     END {
          for (s in str) {
              print s, str[s]
          } 
     }' filename
```

builds an associate array (i.e. keyed by a string rather than an integer) containing the cumulative totals for each string (field 1).

When it has read all of the input, it prints out each element of the array.

```
ghd,40
abc,40
xyz,30
```

pipe through `sort` if you want sorted output.

Comment: This is oneliner territory.  `awk -F, '{s[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in s)print k","s[k]}' filename`.

Comment: @jthill yes, of course it is.  I formatted it for readability since my purpose was to teach and I I wasn't restricted by the limitations of a comment. Or the limitations of a shell command line. It's not exactly a secret that you can format one-liners however you like...even into multiple lines.  as you choose.   BTW, you forgot the `-v OFS=,` - `awk` defaults to a space for OFS, regardless of what FS is set to.

Comment: My purpose is to teach, too. That's why I supplied the oneliner - I think the notion of a oneliner has very substantial value. This one does work, by the way.

Comment: somehow, even after i pointed out that one-liners can be formatted however you like, it has still escaped your notice that my `awk` command above *IS* a one-liner.  hint: it is executed all on one shell command line, it is not a standalone script.  Since it's almost exactly the same as my answer (and you didn't even bother to explain that the only significant difference is that you used a hardcoded `","` rather than setting OFS) it's hard to see ANY educational value in your nitpick.  seems more like egotism than teaching to me.